# Show "thrown error"/"console.log" at the swagger ui

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-ui, openapi-generator, nestjs-swagger

Is it possible to show thrown error/console.log at the swagger ui, when one execute a call from the ui?

I don't know how to start with this and I didn't found any hint by searches in the internet. Maybe someone has a deeper view inside and can answer this fast and reliable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.